# How to allow processing dask futures to finish after exception?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am in the early stages of rewriting my framework for incremental building of scientific analyses to use the incredible Dask -- here dask.distributed.  The dependency graph gets complex, with some tasks running for a long time (hours, days) and others not (minutes).  Each task stores its results to disk along with a user produced key (pure=True, relatively speaking).
When exception handling, I want to allow any tasks that have already started processing, and aren't in an error state, to finish, so that if these are long running tasks their work isn't lost.

I prefer not to hold onto futures to avoid memory consumption.  So one possibility is to retrieve the keys from the scheduler task state, and recreate the futures by calling Future(key), and then use as_completed to allow these to finish.  For some types of exceptions ---eg broken connections -- I might attempt to fix and resubmit the faulty task and keep the whole shebang running -- but rather unlikely.

Oddly, I haven't come across reference to recreating a Future obj in this way in the great documentation and tutorials.
Questions:

1. Is there a reason not to, or pitfalls to avoid, if recreating Future objs from keys?
2. Is there a better way to allow these tasks to finish?  I understand my use case is somewhat unusual in that I store 'intermediate' task results to disk -- otherwise likely little reason to let tasks finish if the larger graph in error.

A toy example which 'works' -- here the subgraph with cellc, celld, and celle can finish after the remainder of the graph is in error.  One major difference is that I would produce and submit keys for each task.

```
from dask.distributed import Client, Future
client = Client()

def cella(i, j):
    return i * j

def cellb(i, j):
    sleep(10)
    return i + j

def cellc(i, j):
    sleep(10)
    return i - j

def celld(x):
    return 10/x

def celle(y):
    return 10/y

def cellf(z):
    return 10/z


def run_top(x, y, z):
    
    futf = client.submit(cellf, z)
    fute = client.submit(celle, y)
    futd = client.submit(celld, x)
    futc = client.submit(cellc, futd, fute)
    futb = client.submit(cellb, futd, futf)
    futa = client.submit(cella, futb, futc)
    
    try:
        result = futa.result()
        
    except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
        # potentially fix and resubmit error task identified in exc

        ix = [Future(key) for key,v in client.cluster.scheduler.tasks.items() if v.state == 'processing']
        
        for fut in distributed.as_completed(ix):
            print(fut,fut.result())
            
        raise exc
    else:
        return result

r = run_top(1,2,0)
```

<Future: finished, type: builtins.float, key: cellc-339ad1ba637073781b981b964aca2337> 5.0

---

ZeroDivisionError    Traceback (most recent call last)...